# What happens if I kill the shepherd's sheep?

Tags: dlc-quest

I just got a sword, and the shepherd made sure to tell me not to harm his sheep, and put up a helpful sign to remind me.

[image: myself, the sign, my sword, and the sheep]

This sheep has done nothing against me, yet all the pushing against it makes me tempted to attack this sheep. Is there a reason to kill or not kill this sheep.

Comment: I tried to add the Mass-Effect-3 tag, then I caught myself. >.>

Comment: @RavenDreamer does Shepard own a flock?

Comment: @RavenDreamer This is why I corrected the spelling. I had also typed out a similar comment 45 minutes ago, but comments were broken for me from mobile site for some reason.

Comment: lol i thought this was someone trying to be funny, +1 for misjudging you c:

Comment: what is the name of this game?

Comment: @Paralytic: DLC Quest. It's pretty short, but I got it in the Indie Royale St.Patrick's Day Bundle last week.

Comment: @Paralytic It's called "DLC Quest."  It was part of the recent Indie Royale bundle.  It's available on Desura, but not Steam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an in-game "awardment" **Anything For An Awardment** is awarded for killing all the NPCs and sheep in the game.  There's no negative side effect.

[image]

Comment: ...well, that's interesting... I think I'll pass still, though.